# Unable to run shell commands with * using python subprocess module

Tags: python, linux, shell, subprocess

I am not able to run any commands using python subprocess module which contains `*` sign in the command.
I am using the call this way,

```
 subprocess.Popen(
            'cp /etc/varnida_sys/* /tmp/bucket/'.split(),
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

For this I am getting,

```
cp: cannot stat ‘/etc/varnida_sys/*’: No such file or directory
```

Why is this error coming, there is one file inside **/etc/varnida_sys/genders**

My investigations says that using regex like * needs some special handling. I am getting some errors in all those commands that contains *.

PS. I am not getting errors when I am running the same command through paramiko from remote host.

Comment: Added [tag:linux]. It doesn't work (as explained by eugene) on Linux but it does on Windows (replacing `cp` with `copy` or running with `powershell -c cp ...`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*` is only understood by a shell (which expands it to a list of files), you need to pass `shell=True` to `Popen()`. Also, there's no need to split the command, you can use a string:

```
subprocess.Popen("cp /etc/varnida_sys/* /tmp/bucket/",
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]
```

As @triplee has suggested below, it's better to use some convenience  wrapper for this task, e.g. [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

```
subprocess.call("cp /etc/varnida_sys/* /tmp/bucket/", shell=True)
```

Comment: However, you want the much simpler `subprocess.call()` instead. The requirement for `shell=True` still holds.

Comment: @tripleee: from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) `on subprocess.call()`: Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function. The child process will block if it generates enough output to a pipe to fill up the OS pipe buffer as the pipes are not being read from.

Comment: And what output do you expect? There should be none; or use `subprocess.check_output()` instead. My point is that `Popen` is needlessly complex for trivial tasks; that is why there is a number of convenience wrappers for common scenarios.